# Partial Matching two data frames having a common column(by words) in R/Python

Tags: python, regex, r, agrep

I have two dataframes as csv files where `df1` has more rows than `df2`:

`Df1`

```
Name                         Count
xxx yyyyyy bbb cccc           15
fffdd 444 ggg                 20
kkbbb ccc dd 29p              5
22 cc pbc2 kmn3 b23 efgh      4
ccccccccc sss qqqq            2
```

`Df2`

```
Name
xxx yyyyyy bbb cccc
ccccccccc sss qqqq pppc
22 cc pbc2 kmn3 b23,efgh
```

I want to do partial matching(approximate/fuzzy matching) by matching either first two/three words. Basically the output will be like this:

Output:

```
Name                       Count
xxx yyyyyy bbb cccc         15
22 cc pbc2 kmn3 b23 efgh    4
ccccccccc sss qqqq          2
```

By trying exact matching, I'm missing some of the rows. I tried with `agrep` in R but somehow its not working and fuzzy matching is quite slow. Please suggest me a way to do this in R or python. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can use `agrep` for fuzzy matching. You can use the `max.distance` parameter to set the maximum distance allowed for a match.

```
DF1[sapply(DF2$Name, agrep, DF1$Name, max.distance = 0.2), ]

#                       Name Count
# 1      xxx yyyyyy bbb cccc    15
# 5       ccccccccc sss qqqq     2
# 4 22 cc pbc2 kmn3 b23 efgh     4
```

---

The data:

```
DF1 <- read.table(text = "Name                         Count
'xxx yyyyyy bbb cccc'           15
'fffdd 444 ggg '                20
'kkbbb ccc dd 29p'              5
'22 cc pbc2 kmn3 b23 efgh'      4
'ccccccccc sss qqqq'           2", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF2 <- read.table(text = "Name
'xxx yyyyyy bbb cccc'
'ccccccccc sss qqqq pppc'
'22 cc pbc2 kmn3 b23,efgh'", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was working with the same code but its very slow when the data size is big. Do you know any other faster method to do this?

Comment: @warwick12 Unfortunately, fuzzy matching is quite slow. You can try an iterative approach where you remove the matches from the set of possible matches to decrease to number of comparisons in each step. Of course, you have to keep track of the original row number.

Comment: Nice answer.  Does stringdist() only apply to numeric matching?

Comment: Thanks you! I'm getting this error. Do you know the possible reason for this error: Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'?

Comment: @warwick12 I suppose the algorithm found more than 1 match for a string.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein : Thanks, any possible solution for this kind of data?

Comment: @warwick12 Do you want to return all matches in this case?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. No, duplicates. I tried using [[2]] but still some error.

Comment: @warwick12 Try `DF1[unlist(lapply(DF2$Name, agrep, DF1$Name, max.distance = 0.2)), ]`.

Comment: Silly me, I tried unlist but forgot to change sapply with lapply. Thank you :)